# Where In SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one question, I am trying to make one `WHERE` statement in Oracle SQL.

As result for the TARGET_ADDRESS column, I need the value from this column only if `ENTRY_POINT = +322012345`, otherwise it should be `null`.

[table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxwx0.png)

Is it possible? It's possible to used `CASE` but I want keep my column TARGET_ADDRESS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include any queries that you have already tried.

Comment: SQL queries have a WHERE *clause*, consisting of one or more *conditions*. The whole query is the [statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the following `CASE` expression should work:

```sql
SELECT t.*, CASE WHEN ENTRY_POINT = '+322012345' THEN TARGET_ADDRESS END AS TARGET_ADDRESS
FROM yourTable t;
```